# How to pass an open socket between view controllers (storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, ios6, storyboard, gcdasyncsocket

Xcode iOS 6 with storyboard. I am adding a chat feature to an already existing program. I am using GCDAsyncSocket. 
Everything works perfectly when I stay within one viewcontroller. I need to have access to the open socket from many viewcontrollers. I also need to access the GCDASYNCSOCKET from from these viewcontrollers.

Does anyone have some example code that might help me?

Will using perpareforsegue allow me to pass an open socket? 
Any singleton that I have seen does not seem to take into account an already existing class like GCDASYNCSOCKET and does not seem to work.

Please help me with some working examples.

Singleton.m

```
#import "SocketConnection.h"
#import "GCDAsyncSocket.h"



@implementation SocketConnection

static GCDAsyncSocket *socket;

+ (SocketConnection *)getInstance;

{

static dispatch_once_t once;
static SocketConnection *instanceOfSocketConnection;
dispatch_once(&once, ^ {instanceOfSocketConnection =[[SocketConnection alloc] init];});
return instanceOfSocketConnection;
}
- (id)init
{
NSString *host = @"xxx.xxxxx.com";
uint16_t port = 5467;


if (socket == nil)
{
    socket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self         delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
}

if (![socket isConnected])
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![socket connectToHost:host onPort:port error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error connecting: %@", error);
    }

}

return self;
}

-(void) socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *) socket didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(uint16_t)port
{
NSLog(@"Connected");

}


@end
```

Singleton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GCDAsyncSocket.h"

@interface SocketConnection : NSObject{}


+ (SocketConnection *)getInstance;
@end
```

This code (singleton) give me an error

When I try to access it from another viewcontroller I get an error (incompatible pointer types assigning to 'GCDAsyncSocket" _strong' from SocketConnection)

```
socket = [SocketConnection getInstance];
```

Comment: You can pass any reference you like during prepareForSegue, and your singleton description sounds pretty vague. Can you show some of the code you've tried?

Comment: jrTurton - I have added code from my singleton above.  If you are saying I can use prepareForSegue to "move" my open socket to another viewcontroller that might be easier. As I have gave up on putting the code in my AppDelgate and went with the singleton which does not seem to work either.  Suggestions thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code I see that your error (`incompatible pointer types assigning to 'GCDAsyncSocket" _strong' from SocketConnection`) clearly describes why it crashes.

In your `+getInstance` method you return `SocketConnection`, and trying to assign it to a `GCDAsyncSocket` type ivar. Make a property or another method to provide access to internal `socket` variable.